# How to display a dataframe from views to django template

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have created an application in django where i read a csv file and stored it in media folder. Next i converted the csv file into pandas dataframe now i need to render the dataframe into my template and display it as a bootstrap table(atleast a general table tag). How should i send the dataframe and how to display it as bootstrap table in template. Thank You

Views.py

```
def dq(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']

        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)

        file_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '\\' + uploaded_file.name

        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)


    return render(request,'dq.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

Views.py (FBV)

```
df_html = df.to_html(index=False)
return render(request, 'dq.html', {'df_html': df_html})
```

Views.py (CBV) (recommended)

```
class View(...View):

    template_name = 'dq.html'        

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):    
        context = super(View, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ... # In your case.
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        context['df_html'] = df.to_html(index=False)
        return context
```

In your html: (dq.html)

```
{{df_html}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html),

```
def dq(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']

        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)

        file_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '\\' + uploaded_file.name
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        html = df.to_html()

    return render(request,'dq.html', {'html': html})
```

dq.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{html|safe}}
</body>
</html>
```

And you can design the table.